# How to update a Mac mini

Tags: macos, mac

I have Mac mini with Mac OS X 10.5.8. I want to upgrade it with latest Mac OS. How can I update Mac OS X? Do I need latest Mac OS X DVDs to upgrade it? Or is it possible to upgrade Mac OS X via the internet?

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the Snow Leopard (10.6) Upgrade on DVD. [It's just $29.99.](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MAC_OS_X_SNGL)

Answer (score 2):

- Your title asks about update and your questions asks about upgrade.  [Updating and upgrading are different](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1444)
- You need an **upgrade DVD** to  [upgrade](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MAC_OS_X_SNGL)  from a one Mac OS to another OS. You can order a upgrade DVD from the apple website which will be shipped to your door-house.
- You dot need any DVD to [update](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1338). Just follow the instructions given in Apple FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

While it's still here, might as well answer: You need an update DVD, can be ordered online or from your friendly neighbourhood Apple Store.